# Vue router-link not reload the page for current route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In VUE when I click a router link in current route the component not reload.
Suppose my current route 
`http://localhost:3000/` when I click my logo this component not reloading.

```
<router-link  class="navbar-brand logo-main" to="/">ABC</router-link>
```

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Why should it reload if you are in the route?

Comment: Vue is primarily a [SPA framework](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/). Not reloading is the expected and correct behaviour. If you want to reload, use native `<a href="/">ABC</a>`.

Comment: If you need a route or component to reload then there are a number of methods to do this. One I would recommend is make a key and have the key change that will force reload. 
Check out this article for more detail:
https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render

Comment: Can you provide more code please.....did you tried .. to="{path  : 
'/' }"

Comment: This is likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Ideally you should be detecting the route change inside the component (either by watching `$route` or using a router hook) and updating the component accordingly, instead of reloading the component from scratch.